# How to get an AWS Neptune gremlin query to filter by pricing_id

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune, gremlinpython

I have a working query using gremlin_python that looks like the following (simplified to focus on the issue)

```
client.graph.V().as_('origin') \
        .outE().as_('p1r1') \
        .inV().as_('midpoint') \
        .outE().has('pricing_id', select('p1r1').pricing_id).as_('p1r2') 
        .inV().
```

So in this, I have 2 edges (p1r1 and p1r2) and I'm just checking that a value of p1r1 is equal to the same value of p1r2.

How can I rewrite this in gremlin to allow for that? So far I have the following but I can't get the select('p1r1').pricing_id to work. It doesn't like the ".pricing_id" part of the notation.

```
"gremlin" :"g.V().as('origin') \
            .outE().as('p1r1') \
            .inV().as('midpoint') \
            .outE().has('pricing_id', select('p1r1').pricing_id).as('p1r2') 
            .inV().
```

For reference I'm sending this through the gremlin API for AWS Neptune.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, while it is something that can hopefully be addressed in the future, Apache TinkerPop Gremlin does not allow for queries of the form:

```java
has(key,<some-traversal>)
```

All that is allowed is:

```java
has(key,<P predicate>)
```

For example:

```java
has(key,eq('123ABC'))
```

If you try something like:

```java
has(key,select('x'))
```

the query will not always error out, depending on how you issue it (text vs bytecode), but it will never do what it looks like it should.

The query needs to be rewritten to use the `where...by` syntax.

For example, in your specific case:

```java
outE().as('x').
where(eq('x')).
  by('pricing_id').
  by(select('p1r1').values('pricing_id'))
```

**Edited 2023-03-03** To show why `has(key,select())` does not work.

Consider the example below. The values 1 and 2 are clearly not the same. However, as `select('x')` returns something, as far as the `has` step is aware, that is treated as a match. This is something that hopefully will be improved in a future TinkerPop release. Until that time, the best way to do these types of operations, is using the `where...by` syntax.

```java
gremlin> g.V(3).values('runways')
==>2
gremlin> g.inject(1).as('x').V(3).has('runways',select('x'))
==>v[3]
```

Comment: Great, thank you! I ended up doing something very similar:

"gremlin" :"g.V().as('origin') \
            .outE().as('p1r1').values('pricing_id').as('p1_id') \
            .select('p1r1').inV().as('midpoint') \
            .outE().has('pricing_id', select('p1_id')).as('p1r2') 
            .inV().

Comment: That looks like it’s using the syntax I described above as maybe not failing but not actually working. The has() will be true always if that select returns any kind of result.  You need to use the `where by` syntax

Comment: I updated the answer to show why `has` cannot be used with `select` currently.

Comment: What am I doing wrong? 
g.V().outE('seg_1_of_2').as('p1r1').inV().as('dest1').V().outE('seg_cont').as('p1r2').where(eq('p1r2')).by('pid').by(select('p1r1').values('pid')).select('p1r1','p1r2').limit(1)

That outputs: "The provided start does not map to a value: e[7ac38aeb-9ba6-3ed2-4b92-596bed8dea92][76c38ab1-3e97-3687-3c22-dd3713211df5-seg_continuing->82c38aad-d6c1-3e1e-1ca7-e85c92e959f9]->[SelectOneStep(last,p1r1), NeptunePropertiesStep([pricing_solution_id],value)]",
    "requestId": "d5b509e5-0ad2-40e1-8dc4-f15398804b24",
    "code": "InvalidParameterException"

Comment: Perhaps ask that as a new question which will make it a bit easier to read etc. Happy to try and help.