# AWS Neptune error using whereby to filter

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I'm trying to get this `where...by` notation working on a query but it's giving me the following error, what is wrong? Tried following this [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75621341/how-to-get-an-aws-neptune-gremlin-query-to-filter-by-pricing-id):

```java
g.V().outE('seg_1_of_2').as('p1r1').
      inV().as('dest1').
      V().outE('seg_cont').as('p1r2').
      where(eq('p1r2')).
        by('pid').
        by(select('p1r1').values('pid')).
      select('p1r1','`p1r2').
limit(1)
```

That outputs:

```
"The provided start does not map to a value: 
e[7ac38aeb-9ba6-3ed2-4b92-596bed8dea92][76c38ab1-3e97-3687-3c22-dd3713211df5-seg_continuing->82c38aad-d6c1-3e1e-1ca7-e85c92e959f9]->[SelectOneStep(last,p1r1), NeptunePropertiesStep([pricing_solution_id],value)]", "requestId": "d5b509e5-0ad2-40e1-8dc4-f15398804b24", "code": "InvalidParameterException"
```

Comment: Does it work if you reverse the order of the two `by` modulators? Also be aware that the query can fan out a lot depending on the results of the first `V`. The second `V` will be applied to each of those results. Perhaps you can also try `where(eq('p1r1')).by('pid')` as you are currently at `p1r2` before the `where`.

Comment: That worked, tried the where(eq('p1r1')).by('pid'). It fans out a lot in the example, but I have the node to start for the second V() in practice so I'll narrow it down to a single node from there, thanks for the heads up though!

Comment: Glad it worked - I'll add that as an answer in case others have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

As the query is already at `p1r2` you should just be able to use `where(eq('p1r1')).by('pid')`. I added the full query with that change below.

```java
g.V().outE('seg_1_of_2').as('p1r1').
      inV().as('dest1').
      V().outE('seg_cont').as('p1r2').
      where(eq('p1r1')).
        by('pid').
      select('p1r1','`p1r2').
limit(1)
```